# apache shiro cannot check md5 password with PasswordMatcher

Tags: shiro

I am using shiro 1.4.0.

My password is MD5, iff I use `HashedCredentialsMatcher`, then I can login successful:

```
  [main]

    shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp
    shiro.successUrl = /home.jsp
 passwordMatcher=org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
    passwordMatcher.hashAlgorithmName=MD5
    passwordMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded=true

    ds = com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource
    ds.driverClass = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    ds.jdbcUrl = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simple_shiro_web_app
    ds.user = test
    ds.password = 123456

    jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
    jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
    jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE username = ?
    jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role_name FROM USERS_ROLES WHERE username = ?
    jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT permission_name FROM ROLES_PERMISSIONS WHERE role_name = ?
    jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $passwordMatcher
    jdbcRealm.dataSource=$ds

    securityManager.realm = $jdbcRealm
```

But if I use `PasswordMatcher`(there is no any error message at tomcat startup), then I login failed:

```
passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
passwordService.hashService.hashAlgorithmName=MD5
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService
```

It seems that is still use default `SHA-256`, why?

Also, in 1.4, there are same class as well as same package name(e.g. `org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.DefaultHashService.class`) in `shiro-core.jar` and `shiro-crypto-hash.jar`, what are the difference and why?

-------------- **UPDATED** -------------------------

There is one log message :

```
TRACE ClassUtils.forName - Unable to load class named [e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f] from the current ClassLoader.  Trying the system/application ClassLoader...
```

While `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f` is my md5 password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the debug, I found that `DefaultPasswordService` use `base64` hash format.
After I changed hash format to `hex`, then it works.

```
<bean id="hexFormat" class="org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.format.HexFormat">

    </bean>

     <bean id="passwordService" class="org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService">
        <property name="hashService" ref="hashService" />
        <property name="hashFormat" ref="hexFormat" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any warnings in your logs?  If not `LdapRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo()` and see if you are getting the password you are expecting.

In 1.4 some of the code has been moved into other modules (though they will resolve the same way as pre 1.4)

Comment: I found one log `TRACE ClassUtils.forName - Unable to load class named [e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f] from the current ClassLoader.  Trying the system/application ClassLoader...`, while `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f` s my md5 password.